# Google Maps - Polygon - overlay text

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap, polygon

is it possible to put a text into polygon class (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon) of google maps? Because if I could draw polygon that contains text, I know that I should use generating of Bitmap, that I'll try to fit into GroundOverlay, but the image is the shaky/not smooth/not-nice curved because of the fact, that I use Bitmap with 300x300 dimensions. But that dimension can't be universal.

Many thanks